# how do style an achor tag active state wrapped around an image tag

Tags: html, css, frontend

I want to code the active state of the anchor tag to change the overlay class opacity to 1.
I am only able to do that using the :hover pseudo with the image to achieve this. Once try to use the link (anchor tag) in styling the image doesn't appears as a link anymore.

```css
.card{
    order: -1;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
}


.card > a{
    display: block;
    position: relative;

}


.card a img{
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 50%;
    border-radius: 20px;
/*  align-self: center; */                      /* centert the image cross-wise (horizontally) */
    padding: 12px;
/*  margin-top: 12px;*/
}


.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  bottom: 12;
  left: 12px;
  right: 12;
  height: 92%;
  width: 90%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #00FFF8;
  border-radius: 13px;

}

.card > a:active .overlay{
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <section id="card_details">
        <h1><a href="#">Equilibruim #3429</a></h1>
        <p>Our Equilibruim collections promotes balance and calm.</p>
        <div class="card">
            <a href="#" aria-label="clink" class="cardlink"><img src="images/nft.jpg" alt="" class="image"></a>
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="eye">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="48" height="48"><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="M0 0h48v48H0z"/><path d="M24 9C14 9 5.46 15.22 2 24c3.46 8.78 12 15 22 15 10.01 0 18.54-6.22 22-15-3.46-8.78-11.99-15-22-15Zm0 25c-5.52 0-10-4.48-10-10s4.48-10 10-10 10 4.48 10 10-4.48 10-10 10Zm0-16c-3.31 0-6 2.69-6 6s2.69 6 6 6 6-2.69 6-6-2.69-6-6-6Z" fill="#FFF" fill-rule="nonzero"/></g></svg>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>
```

The only way I'm getting the overlay to work is with this css below;

```css
.card:hover .overlay{
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

[Below is the live link for the outcome](https://sammiie.github.io/NFT-preview-card/)

Answer (score 1):

Your  active state css doesn't work since `.overlay` is not a child of `.cardlink`.

```css
.card{
    order: -1;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
  max-width:25%;
}


.card > a{
    display: block;
    position: relative;

}


.card a img{
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 50%;
    border-radius: 20px;
/*  align-self: center; */                      /* centert the image cross-wise (horizontally) */
    padding: 12px;
/*  margin-top: 12px;*/
}


.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  bottom: 12;
  left: 12px;
  right: 12;
  height: 92%;
  width: 90%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #00FFF8;
  border-radius: 13px;

}

.card > a:active+.overlay{
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.overlay{
  user-select:none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <a href="#" aria-label="clink" class="cardlink" ><img src="https://sammiie.github.io/NFT-preview-card/images/nft.jpg" alt="" class="image"></a>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="eye">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="48" height="48">
        <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
          <path d="M0 0h48v48H0z" />
          <path d="M24 9C14 9 5.46 15.22 2 24c3.46 8.78 12 15 22 15 10.01 0 18.54-6.22 22-15-3.46-8.78-11.99-15-22-15Zm0 25c-5.52 0-10-4.48-10-10s4.48-10 10-10 10 4.48 10 10-4.48 10-10 10Zm0-16c-3.31 0-6 2.69-6 6s2.69 6 6 6 6-2.69 6-6-2.69-6-6-6Z" fill="#FFF" fill-rule="nonzero" />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You will also need to disable pointer events on the overlay element – otherwise you won't get any focus on your `<a>` element.

```
.card > a:active+.overlay{
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.overlay{
  user-select:none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: disabling the pointer events and using the styling as you gave it made the active state work with the overlay.

so thanks @herrsterietzel